# Confusion about theorem in Eisenbud's commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I am not quite sure what he means in theorem 3.10, the theorem states:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, and let M be a finitely generated $R$-module. Any proper submodule $M'$ of $M$ is the intersection of finitely many primary submodules. Futhermore, if $P_1,...,P_n$ are prime ideals and we write $M'=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^nM_i$ a $P_i$-primary submodule, then if the intersection is minimal, in the sense that there is no such intersection with fewer terms, then each associated prime of $M/M'$ is equal to $P_i$ for exactly one index $i$. In this case, if $P_i$ is minimal over the annilator of $M/M'$, then $M_i$ is the $P_i$-primary component of $0$ in $M'$.

I am confused about the last sentence, since the difinition of $P$-primary component of $0$ is

> If $M$ is any module and $P$ is a minimal prime over $Ann(M)$, then the submodule $M'\subset M$ defined by $$M'=\ker(M\to M_P)$$ is $P$-primary because $M/M'$ injects into $(M/M')_P=M_P$. In this situation, $M'$ is called the $P$-primary component of $0$ in $M$.

The last sentence of the theorem states that $M_i$ is the $P_i$-primary component of $0$ in $M'$, but $M_i$ is not submodule of $M'$ how could the statement be true in this case? If we replace $M'$ with $M/M'$, we also have to change $M_i$ into the its image in the quotient module. If we just modify $M'$ into $M$, then we need $P_i$ to be a minimal prime over $Ann(M)$ but I wonder if one can deduce this from the fact that $P_i$ is minimal over $Ann(M/M')$? So what might be the most possible version of the statement above?

The proof of the theorem in the book assumes $M'=0$, and it is hard to tell the difference between $M$ and $M/M'$ in terms of in which module the $M_i$ should be.